# Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-play-services

[image]

When I install Firebase in my Flutter project, it doesn't work. I have never encountered such an error before. I do as usual. I added the google-services.json file in the app folder of my project. I do not know what the problem is.

Comment: `classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15'`

Firebase is incorrectly showing the dependency text we need to add. The problem was solved by fixing it like this:

**classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'`**